# Asignar URL a APP nodejs

Tags: php, nodejs, apache, url

tengo varios proyectos web que utilizan apache, php y MySQL y estoy implementando nodejs en otro proyecto quisiera saber como asignarle una url con un Alias [www.example.mx/node](http://www.example.mx/node)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: ¿te refieres a que quieres acceder a diferentes aplicaciones bajo el mismo dominio? es decir `www.example.com/node` (aplicacion en node) `www.example.com/php` (aplicacion en php)